# what does "そうなんだよな" mean? (in the context of the following sentence/image))

Tags: manga, english-to-japanese, japanese-to-english

**そうなんだよな** そもそもオレが 旅を始めた 理由って ここのくじらを 見ることであって 終着点に 来てしまった 今 次のことなんか まだ 考えもつかず 綺麗だったな くじら

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still studying Japanese and live in Japan, so please take my words with a grain of salt when compared to an actual fluent speaker.

I think that なん in this case is used to emphasize the previous word: "そう". So without なん the sentence would be: そうです which has the feeling of the meaning- "that's right..." or "oh, yeah...( it's true that...)".   Again, sorry if I can't actually encapsulate the meaning.

So, if I were to hazard a guess - it would just be that: "That's ***right***.."